# Show/ Hide Rows from Dynamic Tables

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a table of list of province from database.

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM province";
$result = mysql_query($query);?>

<table border='1'>
<tr><th>No</th>
    <th>Area Name</th>
    <th>Area (sq km)</th></tr><?
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))  {?>
<tr><td><?=$data['No']?></td>
    <td><?=$data['Province']?></td>
    <td><?=$data['Area']?></td></tr><? }?>
</table>
```

What I need is if I click on one row, let say Province A, some rows will show under Province A that contain list of Cities in Province A.

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM city";
$result = mysql_query($query);?>
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))  {?>
<tr><td><?=$data['No']?></td>
    <td><?=$data['City']?></td>
    <td><?=$data['Area']?></td></tr><? }?>
```

But list of cities under other Province no need to be shown.
Then, when I click again the row of Province A, list of cities under province A will be hide again.

Under the city, there is other list of district from other database table and under district there is list of buildings from other database table.

I need the same feature also happen to city & district, that I can show & hide the list under them by click on the row.

Since the list is from database that contain hundred of thousands records, I hope the script dont load the data in one time at the beginning, only as per click.

Need your help how to use AJAX in this purpose.

Really appreciate your input.

Comment: You might want to consider using [jQuery DataTables](https://datatables.net)—it's extremely customisable, extensively documented and has a large user base (which means most of the common implementation scenarios are already discussed/demonstrated). There isn't a need to reinvent the wheel ;)